# Consistent absolute position of Font Awesome icons with whitespace?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use absolute position to place Font Awesome icons in the top right corner inside a div. The problem I'm having is that some icons have top and bottom "whitespace" in them (like fa-envelope) and some icons do not (like fa-phone).

The goal is consistent spacing from the border on top and right sides of the icon.

```css
   .item {
      padding:1em;
      margin:0 auto;
      width:50%;
      font-size:14px;
      position:relative;
      border:2px solid red;
      margin-bottom:1em;
      height:10em;
    }
    .corner {
      position:absolute;
      top:0em;right:0em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF=8">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">       
<nav> 
</nav>

 <div class="item">
      <div class="corner">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      Hello world
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="corner">
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      Hello world
    </div>

<footer>   
</footer>

</head>
</html>
```

I put this in a code pen to illustrate what I'm trying to do.
https://codepen.io/timmerbu/pen/yRdBwx

Comment: this is almost impossible without some hacks or changing the icons ... it's like you want the letter `l` and the letter `m` to behave the same while the first one is logically taller than the second one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see what you mean. I know this is a font, but unlike alphabetic characters, they are also icons, and consistent spacing seems like something icons should be able to do. I was hopeful there would be a way. For now, I'm using a kludge to solve the problem with program logic and hard-coded adjustable values for `top`.

Comment: Even if they are icon, they are made like fonts (or with SVG) so it was a dev desicion to make them like that. You only way is to change them or use another icon as you won't find any accurate way that will allow you to handle all the FontAwsome icon. All you can do is hacks.

Answer (score 0):

It is bit painful process if you're dealing with a large amount of icons here. 
But somehow you can do that with accessing the class names of icons that you want to remove the space and add `margin-top: -8px;` to them in css.

Example

```css
.item {
  padding:1em;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:50%;
  font-size:14px;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  height:10em; 
}

.corner {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0em;
  right: 0em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fa-envelope{
  margin-top: -8px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="item">
  <div class="corner">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  Hello world
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="corner">
    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  Hello world
</div>
```